# How to set Image object to stop moving after certain step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

***functionality:***

User is to click on the "TAP ME" image button and when doing so, the main image("Circle") will move from the top of the page to the bottom of the page. Hence, the faster you click on the "TAP ME" image button, the faster it will move down vertically.

***What I Have done:***

I have created the necessary html, css and function required for the above mentioned function. Meaning, user is able to get the circle to move down vertically when the user taps rapidly on the "TAP ME" image button.

***Issue:***

The circle image has got no stop point, hence, the circle will keep moving down vertically when the user taps on the "TAP ME" image button. How am I possible to say for example, set a bottom limit for the circle image, such that the circle image will not be able to keep moving down when user keeps tapping on the "TAP ME" image button? Hence, would like to set the circle image to stop moving down at about 1/4 of the remaining page

I have attached the code for your perusal:

```js
function GameStart() {
  console.log("GameStart");
  //Method to enable star to decrease when 'tap' button is tapped
  var step = 20,
    counter = 0,
    timer = 30;
  var x = document.getElementById('GameStar').offsetTop;
  x = x + step;
  document.getElementById('GameStar').style.top = x + "px";

  //Set CountDown Function
  CounterInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    timer = timer - 1;
    $('#GameTime').html(timer);
    if (counter == 30 && x >= 100) {
      clearInterval(CounterInterval);
      $("#GamePage").hide();
      $("#Congratulations").show();
    } else if (counter == 30 && x < 100) {
      counter = 0;
      timer = 30;
      clearInterval(CounterInterval);
      $("#GamePage").hide();
      $("#GameOver").show();
    }
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
#GameStar {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6.5em;
  left: 500px;
  width: auto;
  height: 1050px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#Tap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: 2100px;
  margin-left: 670px;
  outline: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="background-image: url(lib/Elements/Background.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100%; height:100%;z-index=1;">
  <audio src="lib/Elements/happy.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>
  <img id="GameStar" type="image" src="lib/Elements/The%20Star.png">
  <input id="Tap" type="image" src="lib/Elements/Tap%20here%20button.png" onclick="GameStart()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add a simple if statement that check if it's reached the end before updating its position?

```
 var bottomlimit = <1/4 of remaining page>
 var x = document.getElementById('GameStar').offsetTop;
 if(x < bottomlimit) x = x + step;
 document.getElementById('GameStar').style.top = x + "px";
```